# Another curiously recurring template pattern

Tags: c++, templates, f-bounded-polymorphism

```
template <class Data, class Allocator = std::allocator<Node> >
class Node : public Data {
  // ...
};
```

The question is simple, how to make the above code compile?
The intention is to give Node a possibility to allocate other Nodes (and to provide a default allocator).

Answer (score 6):

You **can't** write it like that:

```
template <class Data, class Allocator>
class Node;

template <class Data, class Allocator = 
  std::allocator<Node<Data, std::allocator<Node<...> >
class Node : public Data {
  // ...
};
```

Because the default argument will have to repeat itself. You can use a tag-type, though

```
struct DefaultAllocatorTag { };

template<typename Alloc, typename Node>
struct SelectAllocator {
  typedef Alloc type;
};

template<typename Node>
struct SelectAllocator<DefaultAllocatorTag, Node> {
  typedef std::allocator<Node> type;
};

template <class Data, class Allocator = DefaultAllocatorTag >
class Node : public Data {
  typedef typename SelectAllocator<Allocator, Node>::type 
    NodeAllocator;
};
```

If it is applicable, i would determine the allocator in the container, though. Like this:

```
template<typename Data, typename Allocator = std::allocator<Data> >
struct Container {
  struct Node : Data { 
    typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<Node>::other NodeAllocator;
    ...
  };
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally I solved it! The solution is to delay specialization of the default allocator until inside of the class where Node is already defined:

```
template <class Data, template<class T> class TAllocator = std::allocator >
class Node : public Data {
  typedef TAllocator<Node> Allocator;
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?:

```
#include <memory>

template<class Data>
class NodeImpl : public Data
{
};

template<class Data, class Allocator = std::allocator< NodeImpl<Data> > >
class Node : public NodeImpl<Data>
{
};

class MyAllocator
{
};

class MyDataClass
{
};

int main()
{
    Node<MyDataClass> node;

    Node<MyDataClass, MyAllocator> node_with_alloc;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really a solution, Node still cannot be allocated. He might as well go with template <class Data, class Allocator = std::allocator<Data> >, it's the same thing essentially.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it compile - what you are trying to create is an "infinite" type.

Let's start with that, you cannot use uninstantiated class template as a template argument. So you need to pass Node to std::allocator, like this:

```
template <class Data, class Allocator = std::allocator<Node<Data, Something> > > 
class Node ...
```

However, what would that something be? Well, std::allocator

The trick is that allocators are required to allocate not only their template argument, but any other type. Declare you class as

```
template <class Data, class Allocator = std::allocator<Data> > class Node ...
```

Then, create allocator for nodes like this:

```
typename Allocator::rebind<Node>::other nodeAllocator(myDataAllocator)
```

[This vcblog post about allocators](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/08/28/the-mallocator.aspx) might help, although it's too focused on iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. This one seems to be more typical. Ie. vector and smart pointer implementations are using something similar. The idea is to privately inherit from the allocator:

```
template <class Data, template <class N> class Allocator = std::allocator>
class Node : public Data, private Allocator<Node<Data, Allocator> > {
  // ...
};
```

The bonus is that in inheritance declaration we can already use Node.